# How to get back the data parameter of the Request Dialog?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to use Facebook's Request Dialog to let user invite their friends. I have a doubt regarding the `data` paramenter of the request dialog.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

**data:** Optional, additional data you may pass for tracking. This will be stored as part of the request objects created. The maximum length is 255 characters.

If I set this paramenter with an id like 1234, How can I get back this value (1234) when the user authorize the application clicking on the link in the invitation message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks the requests and gets to your page (with the "request_ids" parameter) you should then get the data for the requests.

The url to get the requests from:

> https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/apprequests

You will get a list of the requests and the data for each one (if such was sent).
Get the request that you need, using the id that was passed to you in the request_ids parameter, and in it you should find the "data" field which should hold the data you sent along with the request (1234 in your example).

Read more about the requests in the [Requests guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/).